# updating php selected value in database for opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.x

I am trying to get the selected value in .tpl file from controller and insert into database using model function, here is my codes

account/order.tpl

```
<?php $test ="1" ?>
<select name="order_id" id="order_id" class="form-control">
   <?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
      <?php if ($order['order_id'] == $test) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" 
         selected="selected"><?php echo $order['order_id']; ?></option>
      <?php }else { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"><?php echo 
         $order['order_id']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
<div class="buttons">
   <div class="pull-right">
      <a href="<?php echo $newbutton; ?>" class="btn btn-primary button" name="order_id_new" value="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" 
      selected="selected">"><?php echo $button_submitnew; ?></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

In controller account/order I have am trying to get the selected value from tpl file and insert into a database by calling model

```
if (isset($this->request->get['order_id_new'])) {
    $new = $this->request->get['order_id_new'];
    $results1=  $this->model_account_order->insert_new($new);
}
```

model/account/order

```
public function insert_new($new) {
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "neworder SET order_id = '" . (int)$new. "' WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'");
}
```

My issue is I am not able to get selected values from tpl and also not able to update the value in the database. any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your php logic is true
 You can try this

```
<select name="order_id_new" id="order_id" class="form-control">
   <?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
      <?php if ($order['order_id'] == $test) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" 
         selected="selected"><?php echo $order['order_id']; ?></option>
      <?php }else { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"><?php echo 
         $order['order_id']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```